# In mysql, instead of googling, is there any easy way to know what the error/waring number mean

Tags: mysql, sql

is there any easy way, such as a sql statement like mysql `explain` / `describe` to easyly know what the error or the warning mean.

I have to google many times about different error number / warning number means.

so I wander.

Comment: it will help [SHOW ERRORS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-errors.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL programs have access to several types of error information when the server returns an error.

[**Reference**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/error-messages-server.html)

Error: 1000 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_HASHCHK)

Message: hashchk

Error: 1001 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_NISAMCHK)

Message: isamchk

Error: 1002 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_NO)

Message: NO

Error: 1003 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_YES)

Message: YES

Error: 1004 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_CANT_CREATE_FILE)

Message: Can't create file '%s' (errno: %d)

Error: 1005 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE)

Message: Can't create table '%s' (errno: %d)

Error: 1006 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_CANT_CREATE_DB)

Message: Can't create database '%s' (errno: %d)

Error: 1007 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_DB_CREATE_EXISTS)

Message: Can't create database '%s'; database exists

Error: 1008 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_DB_DROP_EXISTS)

Message: Can't drop database '%s'; database doesn't exist

Error: 1009 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_DB_DROP_DELETE)

Message: Error dropping database (can't delete '%s', errno: %d)

Error: 1010 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_DB_DROP_RMDIR)

Message: Error dropping database (can't rmdir '%s', errno: %d)

Error: 1011 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_CANT_DELETE_FILE)

Message: Error on delete of '%s' (errno: %d)

Error: 1012 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_CANT_FIND_SYSTEM_REC)

**[See More Here](http://www.briandunning.com/error-codes/?source=MySQL)**

Answer (score 1):

For warnings you can use [SHOW WARNINGS Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-warnings.html)

```
SHOW WARNINGS [LIMIT [offset,] row_count]
SHOW COUNT(*) WARNINGS
```

---

Eg

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1 (a TINYINT NOT NULL, b CHAR(4));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(10,'mysql'), (NULL,'test'), (300,'xyz');
Query OK, 3 rows affected, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 3

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1265
Message: Data truncated for column 'b' at row 1
*************************** 2. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1048
Message: Column 'a' cannot be null
*************************** 3. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1264
Message: Out of range value for column 'a' at row 3
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```